# What happens inside of a C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, allocation

I'd like to know what happens when calling a constructor of a class in C++. More specifically, what other functions are called, and how. Does it call some built-in function to construct the object on the stack, or call malloc to construct it on the heap if `new` is used? Is there a default allocator that's used?

In general, is it possible to use classes and objects without calling constructors?

EDIT: A good question that might help what I'm trying to get at, is: why don't constructors return anything? Initially, I think a novice programmer would expect a constructor to return the object, but that isn't the case. What happens instead?

Comment: No syntax exists to "call a constructor". Please give an example of what you mean.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 One could say placement-new is effectively a constructor call.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I mean the end of "auto x = X()" where X is the name of a class.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa Ah, a common misconception. That is not "calling the constructor". I know it looks like you're calling a function called `X`, but you're not. The invocation of the constructor is done for you, hidden behind layers of machinery; what you're doing there is using functional cast notation to request the creation of a temporary of type `X`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat One could say "ooble fooble wooble" if they wanted to

Comment: @HolyBlackCat will saying ooble fooble wooble help me create a constructor that uses error codes instead of exceptions? Because that is the origin of this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I don't get your point. Can you explain why you think placement-new doesn't count as a constructor call?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Because it isn't one. It's placement new. It begins the lifetime of an object. Part of that may involve the [automatic] invocation of a constructor, among other things. A constructor isn't a thing that creates an object; a constructor is an optional extra that performs some post-object-creation tasks.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951093/how-can-i-check-the-failure-in-constructor-without-using-exceptions

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think this response will do, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> what happens when calling a constructor of a class in C++. More specifically, what other functions are called

Class members are initialized. If some of the members are class instances, their constructors are called.

Also the constructors for the base classes are called, if you have any.

> Does it call some built-in function to construct the object on the stack, or call `malloc` to construct it on the heap if `new` is used

It's not a constructor's job to allocate memory for a class instance. The caller does it.

E.g. if you use `new`-expression, it allocates memory (via `operator new`), and then calls the constructor on that memory.

> is it possible to use classes and objects without calling constructors?

Creating a class instance using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) doesn't call a constructor.

Also you can use classes without creating objects at all (i.e. interact with static members).

---

> EDIT: why don't constructors return anything?

A constructor effectively receives an address, and constructs an instance at that address. It doesn't need to return that address, because it was provided by the caller to begin with.

That's just how C++ works.

How else could it work? Let's say you wanted to return an object from a constructor. Would that mean allocating temporary storage in the constructor, constructing an object in it, then making the caller copy the object from that storage? That would require having a working copy constructor. But then how the copy constructor itself would be implemented?

Comment: Sorry, by "is it possible to use classes and objects without calling constructors?" I meant what would be code that has a function equivalent to a constructor without using a constructor. The question was asked for pedagogy.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa You can make a function that would do anything a constructor normally does (initialize class members by calling [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) on each one), but there's one thing you can't do: you can't [begin the lifetime of the object](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1) (without actually calling a constructor or doing aggregate init).

Comment: "Beginning lifetime" is kind of an abstract concept. Even if a constructor does absolutely nothing, you still have to call it for the object lifetime to 'begin'. Using an object not within its lifetime is technically undefined behavior, and bad things may or may not happen. (They are more likely to happen in release builds.)

Comment: Is it possible to create a hand-rolled constructor, then? Doesn't seem like it, considering  a non-hand-rolled constructor must be used to start the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa Yep, formally it's impossible. In practice, you might be able to get away with not starting the lifetime in some cases, especially if compiler optimizations are disabled.

Comment: The constructor will, by most conventional implementations of C++, also implicitly invoke base class constructors as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

> why don't constructors return anything?

The constructor doesn't return the object, it *constructs* the object on a piece of memory, and does so regardless of how that memory was allocated. If you think of the finished object as a building, the constructor is the function that erects the building on a given piece of land. It is not the constructor's job to buy the land, just to build (construct) on it.

A constructor returning the object would be unable to construct objects allocated on the stack or embedded in other objects. Instead, allocation and construction are decoupled, and the constructor effectively receives the pointer to the memory it should work on (exposed as the `this` pointer). That way the same constructor works for both stack and heap allocated objects.

Comment: Would you be able to write a function with identical functionality to a constructor that returns a pointer?

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa If you are looking for a way to entirely skip constructor invocation, that doesn't appear to be formally supported by C++, as explained in the comments on the other answer. It would help to have more details on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

A `Class` is defined by a user and it contains methods and attributes... 
An Object is an instance of a `Class` it created by the Constructor.

So the `new` operator call the constructor and allocate memory, it returns a pointer.
The new operator allocate memory.

Let's create a Class, there is no memory allocation:

```
Class A {
       A(); //User Constructor
};
 Class B {
 private:
 std::string _name;
};
```

`
Let's create a pointer to the Object A with new

`A *a = new A(); //Call the user defined constructor with memory allocation return a pointer of A`

Another way is to instanciate an object without `new`

```
A a; //call the user defined constructor.
B b; //call the default constructor
```

A constructor role is to create an object.
C++ has a default constructor which is called implicitly if the user didn't create Constructor.

Comment: @walnut what would you consider the allocation of memory? Telling the system to reserve an interval of addresses?

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa Allocation is obtaining a pointer to a memory block that can be used to place an object of a given size (and alignment) into it without interfering with other object's memory. The object itself is constructed by the constructor into this memory. Dynamic allocation is the job of `operator new`. Allocation for automatic and static storage duration variables is the job of the compiler (e.g. via stack layout).